# Azure SignalR Service connection not working in Docker

Tags: docker, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

When we are trying to connect the Azure SignalR (serverless mode) from the Docker we are getting the below error -

"**Failed to connect to will retry after the back off period. Error detail: Unable to connect to the remote server. The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain**"

We have used the below code snippet in startup.cs

```cs
services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.EnableDetailedErrors= true;
}).AddAzureSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = AppSettings.SignalREndPoint;
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notify");
});
```

Please help with the solution if anyone has faced the same problem. It's been a blocker for some time now

Azure SignalR should be connected and accessible via Docker.

Comment: Whether it is working from Visual studio ?

Comment: Yes, the code is working fine in local environment. we are getting error only when run it from docker

Comment: `Serverless mode works with Azure Functions to provide real time messaging capability. Clients work with SignalR Service bindings for Azure Functions, called function binding, to send messages as an output binding.` So why not Azure Function?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/concept-service-mode#serverless-mode

Comment: Hi @TinyWang, sorry my bad it's a deafult mode SignalR that we are using.

Comment: ok then I don't have any other ideas. have you tried to published to azure web app to see if the issue is caused by docker?

Comment: We have tested in App Service and local - both working fine we are facing challenge in docker alone